# how to identify table name using a column name if we are not aware about the table name

Tags: metadata, system-tables

how to identify table name using a column name if we are not aware about the table name

Imagine if you have  10000 tables in Database

I am aware about the column name , but i dont know the exact table name .

Could you please advise is there  a chance to find the table name  , using the column name which you are aware about it  already?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? You can query the metadata to find which tables have columns of that name.

Answer (score 3):

You can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS instead of sys.columns

```
SELECT
    TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_SCHEMA,COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE
    COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%MyColumn'
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is for Microsoft **SQL Server** (you should add a `sql-server` tag to your questino in this case!), you can use this query:

```
SELECT
    ColumnName = c.Name,
    SchemaName = SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id),
    TableName = t.name
FROM 
    sys.columns c
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE
    c.name = 'your-column-name-here'
```